# Where can I find the source code for el-ri-1.0.jar?

Tags: java, el

It seems I cant find it anywhere. All I found is the jar with the compiled code inside only.
 I would appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: I don't know where is the code but you can use a decompiler to check the code here. [http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse].

Comment: @Peter: check *info* of `[el]` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was looking for the reference implementation of the Expression Language API by sun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I've found it here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mortbay.jetty/jsp-2.1/6.1.12.rc3/com/sun/el

(It appears that the RI code that has found its way into the Jetty codebase.  That's OK, because the Sun code was released under a GPL license ... according the headers.)

And I saw signs that you could find the reference implementation source-code in the "el" project on http://java.net

UPDATE:

Found it!  Here is the Java.net repository containing the RI source code:  http://java.net/projects/el-spec/sources/source-code/show

Comment: Thanks, that's was I was looking for. I couldn't find it on java.net , but I will check the source inside jetty jsp artifact in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-2.1/6.1.12.rc3/jsp-2.1-6.1.12.rc3-sources.jar

Answer (score -2):

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-el/commons-el/1.0 lead me to http://commons.apache.org/el/download_el.cgi which links to
http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.apache.org//commons/el/source/commons-el-1.0-src.tar.gz